# How to refer shared library in EAR containing EJB jar in it built using maven as separate artifacts

Tags: maven, deployment, weblogic, shared-libraries, ear

I am using maven to build applications.

I have deployed a WAR file containing many common jars as shared library in application server.

I have an artifact (say A-EJB) of packaging type EJB. I have built the ejb jar file.

I have an another artifact (say A-EAR) of packaging type EAR.

I have added A-EJB dependency in pom file of A-EAR. I could build the EAR file and for adding shared library reference, I have added library reference in weblogic-application.xml of EAR.

In my final EAR file, I could see A-EJB.jar file, other dependency jar files of A-EAR artifact.

EAR structure:
--------------APP-INF\lib\some jars
--------------META-INF\application.xml, MANIFEST.MF, weblogic-application.xml
--------------A-ejb.jar

The class files of A-EJB.jar requires reference of common jars in shared library.

Ideally, I am expecting the deployment should happen successfully but this is not happening. Even though I have shared library reference in EAR file, the deployment fails due to classNotFoundException while preparing the EJB module during deployment.

The class files of A-EJB.jar searches for required jar files for reference but they are available in shared library and shared library is not used even EAR file has the reference to it.

Exception:

weblogic.application.ModuleException: Exception preparing module: EJBModule
[EJB:011023]An error occurred while reading the deployment descriptor. The error was:
 ...........................................................

Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
............................................................

So, this means even though EAR had a shared library reference, the ejb.jar present inside the EAR did not have reference to shared library. Is this true ?

Has anyone faced this exception and scenario. Kindly help me about resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use the ear plugin with this settings.. might help..

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <modules>
            <ejbModule>
                <groupId>ur ejb</groupId>
                <artifactId>ur ejb Id</artifactId>
            </ejbModule>
            <jarModule>
                <groupId>......</groupId>
                <artifactId>......</artifactId>
            </jarModule>
            ....
            ....
    Other jar modules to be included other than the one included in dependency tag
            ....
            ....
        </modules>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>false</addClasspath>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <displayName>...name...</displayName>
        <description>........desc.......</description>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks Om. I tried this but did not work out. I dont know what will be the solution for this problem.

Comment: Did u check the deployed path in the server? Is the ejb present along with the support files or present in different location?

Comment: deployment is failing because of classNotFoundException .. Om. I have added only ejb module. There are many jar files in shared library say 150. I could not add all jar files as java module in pom na. I did not mention this b4 to u. Sorry!

Comment: I also have one doubt here. If I want to use the above plugin code, then I should not use my own application.xml file right. I have done like that only. Please confirm whether this is correct.

Comment: I have required common jars in shared library which is deployed separately.. Om. In EAR, the jars required by EJB jar of EAR is not available in lib folder of EAR but EAR has reference to shared library. Hence, I expect EAR to deploy fine but it is not happening.

Comment: What happens when you try to build the ejb project seperately? If the build is getting passed then ur dependency for EJB's are right.
But, EAR is dependent on ejb and I need it to be bundled.  So what needs to be done is, EJB's dependency should be bought along with the EAR. You can mention it in the EAR's assembly.xml.

Comment: But if you think there are more number of jars, then you can create a seperate project called yourprejectname-ear-dependency (something like that) and create a pom that includes all the jars that are needed by ejb in it. Now you can include this project as a depencey for the ear in the assembly and pom. 
This is how we manage huge dependencies in our project.

Comment: Thanks a lot Om. So you mean the EAR containing ejb.jar should contain all the dependency jars required for ejb.jar within lib folder of EAR only. ejb.jar within EAR will not refer jars outside EAR. So shared library concept in this scenario is not useful. Am I correct in understanding ?

Comment: Yeah .. thanks a lot .. Om. Here, my intention is to use shared library [which contains common jars - means they are used in many artifacts say 120] reference in EAR so that the size of the EAR gets reduced. But, shared library will not work in this EAR structure. May be I believe if class files are straight away under EAR, then shared library would have worked. Thanks for you support .. OM. Gr8 help !